# Does ffmpeg not support icod? Where should I start to dig the issue?

Tags: ffmpeg, decoding

I try to decode some video files using ffmpeg, but get errors caused by icod codec.
Here's the file's ffprobe info:

```
user:~$ ffprobe input.mov
ffprobe version 1.2.3 Copyright (c) 2007-2013 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jan 15 2014 23:08:14 with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.8.1-10ubuntu9)
  configuration: --enable-zlib --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-gpl --enable-nonfree --enable-pic
```

...

```
    Stream #0:0(eng): Video: none (icod / 0x646F6369), 1280x720, 52569 kb/s, SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9, 59.94 fps, 59.94 tbr, 5994 tbn, 5994 tbc
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-01-27 05:09:24
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 21:03:24:08
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: pcm_s16le (sowt / 0x74776F73), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16, 1536 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-01-27 05:09:24
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
    Stream #0:2(eng): Data: none (tmcd / 0x64636D74), 0 kb/s
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2014-01-27 05:09:24
      handler_name    : Apple Alias Data Handler
      timecode        : 21:03:24:08
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 0
Unsupported codec with id 0 for input stream 2
```

Comment: Please try a more recent build since the 1.2 branch release can be considered to be old. See the links to Linux builds of `ffmpeg` on the [FFmpeg Download](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html#LinuxBuilds) page.

Comment: Thanks,you're right. The problem is solved in 2.1.

Answer (score 1):

The first step is to always try a recent build. The 1.2 branch release can be considered to be old. [FFmpeg development is very active](http://git.videolan.org/?p=ffmpeg.git;a=shortlog), and using a recent build will ensure that you're not missing a feature or that you're not experiencing a bug that has already been fixed; such as your case with Apple Intermediate Codec (ICOD) decoding.

See the links to Linux builds of ffmpeg on the [FFmpeg Download](http://ffmpeg.org/download.html#LinuxBuilds) page or see one of the many [FFmpeg compile guides](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide).